# Unable to create VPC and routing table using cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, cloud, aws-cloudformation, devops

Iam new to cloud formation. I tried creating vpc,subnet and its routing table using cloud formation.But unable to create it.Anyone please help me to solve the issue.My yaml file is as follows:

```
myvpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
        EnableDnsSupport: true
        EnableDnsHostnames: true
        InstanceTenancy: default
        Tags:
            - Name: gccvpc

myinternetgateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
        Tags: 
            - Name: gccgt

mygatewayattach:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
        InternetGatewayId: !Ref myinternetgateway
        VpcId: !Ref myvpc

mysubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
        VpcId: !Ref myvpc
        CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true


Routetable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref myvpc

Route:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: myinternetgateway
    Properties:
        DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        GatewayId: !Ref myinternetgateway
        RouteTableId: !Ref Routetable
SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref Routetable
        SubnetId: !Ref mysubnet1
```

Comment: Are you getting an error when trying to create a CloudFormation Stack with this template? If so, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Hi Jamie, Actually iam not geting any error. While creating stack it is showing status as ROLLBACK_COMPLETE. But VPC is not created.

Comment: If you look at the Stack events for the stack, you'll likely see that at one point, one of the resources errored, which initiated a rollback. `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` is the end state of an error.

This article will be useful for [Viewing Stack Event History](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-listing-event-history.html)

Comment: yh....thanx for the resource Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the resources condition and your tag properties were incorrect. Please post the error next time which you can find on the events tab in the CloudFormation Console.

```
Resources:
  myvpc:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC"
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/16"
      EnableDnsSupport: "true"
      EnableDnsHostnames: "true"
      InstanceTenancy: "default"
      Tags:
      - Key: "Name" 
        Value: "gccvpc"

  myinternetgateway:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway"
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: "Name" 
        Value: "gccvpc"

  mygatewayattach:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment"
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref "myinternetgateway"
      VpcId: !Ref "myvpc"

  mysubnet1:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: "us-east-1a"
      VpcId: !Ref "myvpc"
      CidrBlock: "10.0.1.0/24"
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: "true"

  Routetable:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::RouteTable"
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref "myvpc"

  Route:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Route"
    DependsOn: "myinternetgateway"
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
      GatewayId: !Ref "myinternetgateway"
      RouteTableId: !Ref "Routetable"

  SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref "Routetable"
      SubnetId: !Ref "mysubnet1"
```

Comment: Sorry George i have placed Resource condition earlier itself.sorry to miss that in my post.Its the tag that was causing issue. Thanks for the help dude.....Now its working fine.